# Storyboard not unloading when switching to another xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

i'm developing an app for the iPhone, and i'm having a bit of trouble with switching views and xibs and storyboards etc. I have gotten everything to work as in switching the views, but when i change to my game view from my main menu, it seems that instead of entirely switching views, it just appends all the objects i added programmatically etc to the same storyboard for some reason, i can see the previous page in the background while the game completely loads and works. The buttons from the previous views also seems to still still work, but are just "ghost buttons" as in i can click them through the new view.

It's almost as if the old view never unloads but just stays there in the background, while the new view gets added on top of the old view. I'm using Xcode Version 5.0.1 (5A2053) and developing for iOS 7. the methods i use for switching views are:

From Storyboard to Xib:

```
[self presentViewController: [iphoneGame alloc] animated: NO completion:nil];
```

From Xib to Storyboard:

```
ViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    [viewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code to load a VC from an XIB is wrong. You don't create a view controller with alloc/init. You need to use initWithNibName:bundle:. If you pass in nil for both, the system should use the nib name that's the same as the class name.

Why are you trying to mix and match VCs from XIBs and storyboards? That's fairly unusual. Most people either use one or the other, and if you're going to do it, the burden is on you to get everything set up correctly.

Comment: well i'm fairly new to app development and i guess there was a storyboard from the start and so i just added a xib for the next view, is that bad? and if so is there a way to "convert" the main storyboard to xib?

Comment: If you're new, stick with storyboards. Add a new scene to your storyboard for the next VC and learn how to link to it. Mixing XIBs and storyboards will just confuse you, and there are some things that you can't do with XIBs,  only storyboards.